# UIPicker Array Data will not display

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have no errors but have ran into this problem...again!

My UIPickerViews will not populate with their respective data from their arrays. When I "build and run" the UIPicker pops up, but the "climateOption" and "environmentOption" do not populate the UIPicker when you click on the UITextField. Here is my code: Thank you for the assistance everyone.

```
@IBOutlet weak var climateTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var environmentTextField: UITextField!


var climateOption = ["Hot", "Warm", "Cold", "Anywhere"]
var environmentOption = ["Beach","City","Mountain","Rural","Anywhere"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let pickerView = UIPickerView()
    pickerView.delegate = self

        climateTextField.inputView = pickerView
        environmentTextField.inputView = pickerView

climateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
environmentTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView == climateTextField {
        return climateOption.count
    } else if pickerView == environmentTextField {
        return environmentOption.count
    }
        return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == climateTextField {
        return climateOption[row]
    } else if pickerView == environmentTextField {
        return environmentOption[row]
    }
        return ""
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView == climateTextField{
        climateTextField.text = climateOption[row]
    } else if pickerView == environmentTextField{
        environmentTextField.text = environmentOption[row]
    }

}


}
```

Comment: You probably did not connect your data source and/or delegate outlets from your picker view to your view controller. Set a breakpoint in `numberOfRowsInComponent` and make sure it's being called. My guess is it's not.

Comment: Being fairly new to iOS, could you explain how to further do that? And as well set a breakpoint to make it call?

Comment: @blakejet1in your storyboard's document outline control drag from UIPickerView to your view controller then click data source and repeat but click delegate. If you don't know how to set a breakpoint try printing something in `numberOfComponentsInPickerView`, if it's logged to the console you know the problem is related to something other than setting the datasource.

Comment: that worked! thank you @beyowulf 

next task...styling the pickerView and UIToolBars within them. If you have any links to assist with that in Swift I'd appreciate it!